# Fan trap and redundant relationships issues

Tags: database-design

Here're a few domain rule resulting the current design of the relations. A project application form can have only one company responsible supervisor, and one company where the project is conducted. A company can have multiple supervisors, and be applied within many project application form. However, a company record together with the company supervisor record are only first created when there's an application on them. The system shall be able to look up company name and find company information, associated supervisor information, and previous project information in the application form. It shall also show a project's company, supervisor when someone process the project application form.
[image]
From the design, I can see one of the relationship is redundant and there's fan trap. How can I resolve these without breaking the domain rules.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to it, expecting an review
[image]